# can I use a clustering model written in python in an iOS application?

Tags: python, ios, cluster-analysis, coreml

I wrote a code with python that uses clustering to detect colours in an image, is there any API's or techniques that I can use the code in my ios application that I want to publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the algorithm uses a library such as OpenCV, you can keep using that (but from C++). Otherwise, you have to rewrite the algorithm in Swift, Objective-C, or C/C++.